# Are there any reasons you might not want to have a foreign_key in an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, foreign-keys, associations

If you have

```
Parent
 has_many :children

Child
```

Is there any reason a foreign key on Child (to Parent) and a corresponding `belongs_to :parent` might not be desirable?

When, if ever, would you not want your Child to be able to access its parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a trade-off.  The usual argument against foreign keys is that the index for a foreign key incurs some performance overhead on insert/update/delete.  *Just like any index.*

But an index also gives great benefit when you search via that column.

```
SELECT * FROM Child WHERE parent_id = :id
```

Also don't underestimate the overhead of searching for orphaned children and cleaning up bollixed references, which are the inevitable consequence of omitting foreign key constraints.

```
-- Typical chore: searching for orphaned child rows.

SELECT c.* FROM Child c LEFT OUTER JOIN Parent p 
  ON (c.parent_id = p.parent_id) 
WHERE p.parent_id IS NULL;
```

There are also some database designs in which you *can't* use foreign keys, such as Polymorphic Associations or Entity-Attribute-Value.  But these designs are anti-patterns in their own right.

Answer (score 1):

Performance.  There is a cost when inserting a child record to determine if there is a parent record.  You can still access the parent record (assuming you have a parentID column in the child table, just no referential integrity).